# Wix Change Text according to checkbox

Tags: wix

Hi I'm writing a installer. Now I have a text control to display a property, I want the change the property immediately (also the displayed value change) according to a checkbox's selection/deselection.

How can I do it?

Comment: This is not possible in Windows Installer UI. It doesn't matter whether you use WiX to build your package or anything else - it's the platform limitation.

Comment: @YanSklyarenko Thanks, but it seems some tricks can do it?

Comment: In terms of setting a property, this is done immediately once you tick the checkbox. But in order to render the changed text based on the checkbox state change, you'll have to refresh the dialog. For instance, stepping Next and then Back can do this trick... but it's ugly user experience...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your use case correctly this is possible. Just define 2 text controls in the same place (one over another) showing different values and then depending on some variable value do hide one and show the other and visa verse.